# I need to get a Speed value from my Horse Class which is a List

Tags: c#

First post on here but, I really need your help. I've been programming c# for school for about a month and got a extra assignment. I need to make a `horse race track game.` You can select how many horses are joining the race etc. My problem here is that I made a Class Horse. I put that in a list like this:

```
        public void maakLijst()
    {


        int aantalpaarden = Decimal.ToInt32(nudAantalPaarden.Value);
        for (int i = 0; i < aantalpaarden; i++)
        {
            paarden.Add(new Horse(i));
        }


    }
```

And I can assign speed to a horse. like this:

```
 private void randomizeSpeed()
    {
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        int afstand = 0;
        afstand = Int32.Parse(tbAfstand.Text);
        foreach (var Horse in paarden)
        {
            Horse.setSpeed(randomizer.Next(afstand / 7, afstand/5));        // De minimale afstand die de paarden afleggen per timertick, is 1/7e van de totale afstand en de verste afstand is 1/5e
        }

    }
```

Which I tested and it worked. But now I need to get the value of speed to make my picture boxes move (I know how to do that).

> Main question is: "How can I get the speed of every horse in the
>   list?"

Edit 1:

this is the class:

```
    class Horse
{
    int nummer;     //Number
    int snelheid;   //Speed
    int afstand;    //Distance

    public Horse()
    {
        nummer = 0;
    }
    public Horse(int num)
    {
        nummer = num;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed)
    {
        snelheid = speed;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance)
    {
        afstand = distance;
    }

    public int getDistance()
    {
        return afstand;
    }

    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return snelheid;
    }

    public int getNummer()
    {
        return nummer;
    }


}
```

Comment: First show your class "Horse", second what you mean get? If you set in foreach loop you can also get it in the same way.

Comment: edited the post, and with "Get" I mean i need the speed value of each horse to use with 1 of 5 pictureboxes. A timer adds the speed to each X position of the pictureboxes

Comment: So where is the problem. Use a `for` loop and update the picture boxes using the current horse's `GetSpeed()`. If you have your picture boxes in an array, you can just select them with the loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    int numberOfHourses = 10;
    var hourses = new List<Horse>();
    int afstand = 70;
    Random randomizer = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHourses; i++)
    {
        var horse = new Horse(i);
        horse.setSpeed(randomizer.Next(afstand / 7, afstand/5)); 
        hourses.Add(horse);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfHourses; i++)
    {
        // get your hourse speed here:
        var speed = hourses[i].getSpeed();
        Console.WriteLine(speed);
    }
}

class Horse
{
    int nummer;     //Number
    int snelheid;   //Speed
    int afstand;    //Distance

    public Horse()
    {
        nummer = 0;
    }
    public Horse(int num)
    {
        nummer = num;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed)
    {
        snelheid = speed;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance)
    {
        afstand = distance;
    }

    public int getDistance()
    {
        return afstand;
    }

    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return snelheid;
    }

    public int getNummer()
    {
        return nummer;
    }
}
```

Quick note: one thing of that make your C# code look better and it follows existing code standards:

Please use PascalCase for all your methods and properties and camelCase for your variables.

For example: `getSpeed` method name should be `GetSpeed`

Comment: Okay thanks i'm gonna try this. this is my first time working with lists so didnt know you could acces the like array with the []

Comment: no problem, this is an *indexers* they use in many built-in types like array and List, Dictionaries, etc  actually they could be implemented to your own classes as well (probably not needed to implement on horse class here, though)

Comment: Yeah i needed to practice with classes so that was the assignment thanks for your help and have a Nice day :D

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for the help guys i didn't know i could acces lists with just list[0] and stuff. I know "amateur hour". first time working with lists so yeah.

```
private void updatePosition()
    {
        int aantalpaarden = Decimal.ToInt32(nudAantalPaarden.Value);

        picRedHorse.Location = new Point(picRedHorse.Location.X + paarden[0].getSpeed(), picRedHorse.Location.Y);
        picYellowHorse.Location = new Point(picYellowHorse.Location.X + paarden[1].getSpeed(), picYellowHorse.Location.Y);
        picGreenHorse.Location = new Point(picGreenHorse.Location.X + paarden[2].getSpeed(), picGreenHorse.Location.Y);
        picBlueHorse.Location = new Point(picBlueHorse.Location.X + paarden[3].getSpeed(), picBlueHorse.Location.Y);
        picPinkHorse.Location = new Point(picPinkHorse.Location.X + paarden[4].getSpeed(), picPinkHorse.Location.Y);
    }
```

now I only need to make it that it doesnt crash when i select less than 5 horses. But I can do that by myself

Answer (score -1):

My Answer is easy
just use the same for block as you did when creating a horse.
this way you can get the speed for each horse when running the game loop.